# IntelliJ Kotlin SDK: Why is my basic EditorMouseMotionListener not working?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am trying to use the[EditorMouseListener](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/idea/232.8660.185/platform/editor-ui-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/event/EditorMouseListener.java) class to ultimately render a popup (or [HintManager](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/notifications.html#editor-hints)) when a line of code is hovered.

I am trying to do a very simple `println("mouse moved")` but I haven't been able to do so. I am using the IntelliJ-plugin template that Jetbrains provides, and modifying the default listener class (MyActivationListener.kt). Like this:

```
internal class MyApplicationActivationListener(val editor: Editor) : EditorMouseMotionListener {
    init {
        println("init called")
        editor.addEditorMouseMotionListener(this)
    }
    override fun mouseMoved(e: EditorMouseEvent) {
        val line = editor.xyToLogicalPosition(e.mouseEvent.point).line

        println("l27 line: $line")
        println("mouse moved:")
```

And also modifying the `plugin.xml` resource to use the EditorMouseListener topic, like this:

```
    <applicationListeners>
        <listener class="com.github.baristageek.watermelonintellij.listeners.MyApplicationActivationListener" topic="com.intellij.openapi.editor.event.EditorMouseMotionListener"/>
    </applicationListeners>
```

[This is all I can find](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/extension-point-list.html#platformextensionpointsxml) about EditorMouseListener class in the SDK docs. So I'm trying to build based on [this example](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/TeamCodeStream/codestream/-/blob/jb/src/main/kotlin/editor/NewCodemarkGutterIconManager.kt?L21:58&popover=pinned).

What do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: I'd recommend you contact IntelliJ IDEA development team directly as per https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/getting-help.html